# Angle between two nearly identical vectors

Tags: r, angle

I found that using

```
angle <- (acos(sum(a*b) / (sqrt(sum(a * a)) * sqrt(sum(b * b)))))
```

is the most common way to get an angle between two vectors `a` and `b` in R.

Unfortunately, I keep on getting errors on certain vectors that seem to lay on each other or have an angle of about 180 degrees between each other.

For example:

```
a <- c(-7.6942088429381328e-01, 2.4999999999999989e-01)  
b <- c(-5.4146791834239578e+08, 1.7593359143824694e+08)
```

do not work.

I am facing similar problems with other ways of calculating an angle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use vector operations.

Let's define a proper function `angle` that takes as arguments two vectors `x1` and `x2`

```
angle <- function(x1, x2, tol = 1e-6) {
    cost <- as.numeric((x1 %*% x2) / (sqrt(x1 %*% x1) * sqrt(x2 %*% x2)))
    if (abs(cost - 1) < tol) return(0) else return(acos(cost))
}
```

Note that we do a numeric stability check to ensure that for angles close to 0, we get a numeric result (instead of `NA`).

Then to calculate the angle (in radians) between two vectors, e.g.

```
x1 <- c(1, 1)
x2 <- c(0.5, 2)
```

we do

```
angle(x1, x2)
#[1] 0.5404195
```

In your case,

```
angle(a, b)
#[1] 0
```

---

Note that this will also work for higher dimensional vectors, e.g.

```
x1 <- c(1, 1, 1)
x2 <- c(0.5, 2, 0)
angle(x1, x2)
#[1] 0.7952027
```